# Remove date between parentheses in PHP

Tags: php, regex, date, parentheses

I would remove the date in parentheses, including the brackets it ourselves, PHP, using **a regular expression**.

Example : `Artist - title (2016)`

And I want this : `Artiste - title`

I have tried many things, but never managed to get a concrete result.

How to do this ?

Comment: what you have tried? put your attempt here

Comment: *I have tried many things,* Show us your regex, so we can see and tell you why you failed and how to fix it

Comment: This kind. I don't know about regex : preg_replace("/\([1-4]+\)/","",$string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$string = "Artist - title (2016)";
echo preg_replace("/\([^)]+\)/","",$string); // Artist - title
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: 1) This will remove more than just dates in parentheses 2) "Hope this helps" and "Try this" are still noise.... won't change in the future